# Median using two lists but from using a function

Tags: python, list, median

I need to write a function called median_fun that returns the median of the list and testing with 2 lists

```py
test_list_1 = [8, 8, 3, 5, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 3, 10, 9]
test_list_2 = [8, 12, 3, 5, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 3, 10, 9]
```

This is the code that I already have but it shows as "none" when I run it.

```py
median_func = []
def median_func(values) :
    length = len(values)
    test_list_1.sort()
    test_list_2.sort()
    if n % 2 == 0:
        median1 = test_list_1[length//2]
        median2 = test_list_2[length//2 - 1]
        median_func = (median1 + median2)/2
print(median_func(test_list_1))
print(median_func(test_list_2))
```

Comment: n is not defined in your code

Comment: I changed n to length now but it says it's not defined

Answer (score 1):

```
list_1 = [8, 8, 3, 5, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 6, 3, 10, 9]
list_2 = [8, 12, 3, 5, 5, 8, 1, 4, 8, 3, 10, 9]

def median_fun(values) :
  length = len(values)
  values.sort()
  if length % 2 == 0:
     median1 = values[length//2]
     median2 = values[length//2 - 1]
     median_fun = (median1 + median2)/2
     return median_fun
  else:
     return values[length//2]
print(median_fun(list_1))
print(median_fun(list_2))
```

I fixed some errors.

You were getting None because you were not returning anything that `print` could show.

I get output:

```
6
6.5
```